# Dateformatter returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The function below works in a playground but when I run it in my app for some reason the `date` and `fDate` returns `nil`. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
extension NSDate{
 func APIformatDate(dateString: String)->String{
     p   let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM"
        let fDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
        return fDate
    }

}
let a = NSDate().APIformatDate("2025-12-18T01:30:00Z")
```

Works in Playground = http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/db3df0ceebe0bc9061c9b200606b59ce93b43c7889f1aa056f4d7afb160beac9

Comment: Specify your input `dateFormat` first before calling `dateFromString`. You put input 18 Dec 2025 and the output is 1 Jan, it surely not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it doesn't work in an iOS playground under Xcode 7.3.1. It crashes trying to unwrap `date` because `"2025-12-18T01:30:00Z"` doesn't match the default format used by `NSDateFormatter`, so `dateFromString` returns nil. Moral: don't trust the IBM Swift Sandbox to behave exactly like iOS or OS X.

Also, since `APIformatDate` doesn't refer to `self`, it should be a `class` or `static` method, or a method on `String`, so you don't have to create an `NSDate` object just to call it.

Also<sup>2</sup>, it is expensive to create an `NSDateFormatter`, so if you're going to call this function often, you should create one formatter for each format and keep them around.

```
extension NSDate {

    static func apiFormatted(iso8601String string: String) -> String {
        return apiFormatter.stringFromDate(iso8601Formatter.dateFromString(string)!)
    }

    private static let iso8601Formatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        return formatter
    }()

    private static let apiFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        let parser = NSDateFormatter()
        parser.dateFormat = "dd-MMM"
        return parser
    }()

}
```

Comment: "Moral: don't trust the IBM Swift Sandbox to behave exactly like iOS or OS X." Right. The IBM Swift Sandbox is based on Swift for Linux, which is not going to operate the same way as iOS/OS X at this time.